# TagHelper PreContent and PostContent not showing up in HTML when overriding InputTagHelper

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, tag-helpers

I want to create a tag helper to put some HTML before and after `<input>` tags, but I want to keep the default `asp-for` behavior and access the `ModelExpression` data.

To this end, I tried to override the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.InputTagHelper` type, as described [in this post](http://rion.io/2017/04/27/extending-tag-helpers-in-asp-net-core-applications/). However, even though I can verify in the debugger that the `Process` method is being called `PreContent` and `PostContent` are both being set, nothing shows up in the HTML other than the standard `<input>` tag. It works fine when creating a tag helper from scratch for another tag though.

I created a small project to demonstrate this issue. I put [the entire project on GitHub](https://github.com/MiffOttah/TagHelperIssue), and I'm copying the specific tag helper I'm trying to create below.

```cs
    [HtmlTargetElement("input", Attributes = "asp-for,test-label")]
    public class TestTagHelper : InputTagHelper
    {
        public TestTagHelper(IHtmlGenerator generator) : base(generator)
        {
        }

        [HtmlAttributeName("test-label")]
        public string Label { get; set; }

        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            output.PreContent.SetHtmlContent($"<b>{WebUtility.HtmlEncode(Label)}</b> ");
            output.PostContent.SetHtmlContent($" <i>({WebUtility.HtmlEncode(For.Name)})</i>"); // access information from the input tag
            base.Process(context, output);
        }
    }
```

Am I missing something obvious? Is there a caveat to doing this? Or is this something that just can't be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this issue, we could try to call `PreElement` and `PostElement` instead of `PreContent` and `PostContent` like

```
[HtmlTargetElement("input", Attributes = "asp-for,test-label")]
public class TestTagHelper : InputTagHelper
{
    public TestTagHelper(IHtmlGenerator generator) : base(generator)
    {
    }

    [HtmlAttributeName("test-label")]
    public string Label { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        base.Process(context, output);
        output.PreElement.SetHtmlContent($"<b>{WebUtility.HtmlEncode(Label)}</b>");
        output.PostElement.SetHtmlContent($"<i>({WebUtility.HtmlEncode(For.Name)})</i>");
    }
}
```

Comment: @MiffTheFox What do you mean did not work? error or any unexpected result? What is your current result?

Comment: It didn't have any change from the code I posted in the thing. There was no post content or pre content being placed in the output HTML, as in the original question. The HTML did not include the <b> and <i> tags. https://gist.github.com/MiffOttah/f1b2de8c945cf8fb8dfb395ab023c2fa

Comment: @MiffTheFox Are you sure you used `PreElement` instead of `PreContent`?

Comment: Yes, that was it. I never even realized it was a different property. I'll edit the answer to point that out.